# Reading after "Java Concurrency In Practice" for more concurrency examples?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Many people at SO adviced to dive into Java concurrency by reading [Java Concurrency in Practice (JCIP)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321349601), sometimes [Doug Lea's book of 1999](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237980/java-5-concurrency-book-recommendations) is mentioned as well:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1237980/java-5-concurrency-book-recommendations
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/452391/recommended-books-on-concurrency-synchronization-mechanisms

After reading JCIP, still feel the **need for recapitulation/consolidation of the topic**. This mainly because I feel the **lack of examples** in JCIP, however the book touches almost all aspects of Java multithreading.

Can you **recommend any book / resources** that would supplement JCIP by lots of examples of java.util.concurrent.* usage?

Any advice or links are welcome. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 9):

here is a summary of the book with examples for your quick reference: https://blogs.oracle.com/carolmcdonald/entry/some_concurrency_tips, http://refcardz.dzone.com/refcardz/core-java-concurrency

here are few more examples: http://www.vogella.de/articles/JavaConcurrency/article.html

Answer (score 7):

I dont know any books that offer better examples then JCiP.  Lea's book of 1999 is a great read for understanding the primitives that were written for java 5.  However, I asked Doug what book he recommends to read and he suggested [The Art  of Multiprocessor Programming](http://www.elsevier.com/wps/find/bookdescription.cws_home/714091/description#description).  All examples that are available are written in Java (though there is some pseudo code).

Alot of 1.6 concurrency implelemntations (skip list algorithm for one) is written based on this book.  Its a great read for how to correctly implement complicated algorithms.

Comment: W. : Thanks for pointing a new source. The irony with concurrency is that there is never "too much" examples of bad/good code, for example I've never seen an open discussion describing and reasoning the changes implemented in 1.6...