# Can I make use of “Java Concurrency In Practice” even if intend to program pthreads or C++ threads?

Tags: multithreading

[Considering that it is considered a good book,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3223652/reading-after-java-concurrency-in-practice-for-more-concurrency-examples)

I want to understand the "concepts" so that I can program threads in any language I want.

That book has Java in the title. Currently I am working with pthreads. Will I be able to make use of that book?

Do the concepts presented in that book also apply to pthreads etc.?

Is there something I need to be wary of?

P.s. I am after learning concepts, am not after syntax.

Comment: Yes, concepts are similar but details are different. I'd rather get David Butenhof's POSIX Threads (I think that was the title) if you're going to use C and POSIX Threads.

Comment: The Java memory concurrency model is somewhat different from C++ and pthreads memory models. It's not that difficult to learn the difference, but unless you can program well in Java, I don't think you'll be able to learn effectively from the book with no way to apply what you've learned to a language you understand.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt thanks for the other book suggestion. Will I have to read some other book for dealing with C++ in future?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz thanks to you too. Can you recommend a threads book which teaches the concepts without relying on a particular language?

Comment: To be honest, I don't know. That book is the only book I ever read about multithreading, the rest I learned from various online resources, practice and peer review.